# Java-spring error: Actual and formal argument differ in length

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the following error:

> Error:constructor Commonctx in class CommonCtx cant be applied to
>   given types; 
>   required: org.springframework.core.env.Environment 
>   found:no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length.

Code being used:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:${input.file.loc}")
public class CommonCtx implements IContext {

    private String tempDir;

    @Autowired
    public CommonCtx(Environment inputProperties) {

        tempDir = inputProperties.getProperty("temp.dir");
...
}

@Component
@Conditional(cond1.class)
@PropertySource("file:${input.file.loc}")
public class NewCCtx extends CommonCtx implements NewCContext{

    private String productName;

    /**
     * @param inputProperties
     */
    @Autowired
    public NewCCtx(Environment inputProperties) {
        this.productName = inputProperties.getProperty("product.name");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this constructor:

```
public NewCCtx(Environment inputProperties) {
    this.productName = inputProperties.getProperty("product.name");
}
```

You should be explicitly calling the super constructor (`CommonCtx`) with its proper argument:

```
public NewCCtx(Environment inputProperties) {
    super(inputProperties);
    this.productName = inputProperties.getProperty("product.name");
}
```

This is required due to your parent class not having a zero-argument constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help. :)